# Converting RGB to Grayscale manually tensorflow

Tags: python, numpy, rgb, tensorflow, grayscale

I wanted to convert an RGB image to grayscale manually without library usage in tensorflow. So I wrote the following...

```
import tensorflow as tf
import matplotlib.image as mpimg
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# First, load the image again
filename = "MarshOrchid.jpg"
raw_image_data = mpimg.imread(filename)

image = tf.placeholder("float", [None, None, 3])
slice = tf.slice(image,[0,0,0],[-1,-1,1])

with tf.Session() as session:
    result = session.run(slice, feed_dict={image: raw_image_data})
    plt.imshow(result)
    plt.show()
```

I extracted the first channel of the image for the conversion. **But this generates error while using imread saying**

```
TypeError: Invalid dimensions for image data
```

What should I do?

Comment: Which line throws the error?

Comment: plt.imshow(result)

Comment: Shubham, have you found the solution for it? I met similar issue while showing the image with imshow

Comment: @Fiona the np.squeeze() in the solution helped me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [doc](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.imshow) of plt.imshow(X):

> X : array_like, shape (n, m) or (n, m, 3) or (n, m, 4)

Here you have an input of shape [None, None, 1]. You just need to remove the last dimension like this:

```
result = np.squeeze(result, 2)
```

Comment: Was my method to convert to grayscale correct, (eliminating 2 channels) or should I go for averaging the 3 channels

Comment: Average ! It is way better